# Rails 3.2 activerecord cookies throwing error

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Occasionally on my local computer, when importing database dump from my production database, I get this when trying to log in:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 5: ..." = '2015-12-21 02:17:25.574627' WHERE "sessions"."" = 40276...
                                                             ^
: UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = 'some data I removed=
', "updated_at" = '2015-12-21 02:17:25.574627' WHERE "sessions"."" = 402761:
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:291:in `translate_exception'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1155:in `translate_exception'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:284:in `rescue in log'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:670:in `exec_delete'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:96:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:359:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:68:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:74:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:71:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `block in update'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__115690163__update__488215436__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_update_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:272:in `update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__115690163__save__488215436__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:323:in `block in set_session'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:50:in `silence'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:320:in `set_session'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:327:in `commit_session'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:211:in `context'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__649130748__call__488215436__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  (gem) eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So I clear the database of sessions (rails dbconsole and delete from sessions;)

But then the error becomes

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 4cb13a797731260dad7f93297f64b0a6, BAh7AA==
, 2015-12-21 02:53:30.976481, 2015-12-21 02:53:30.976481).
: INSERT INTO "sessions" ("created_at", "data", "id", "session_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5):
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:291:in `translate_exception'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1155:in `translate_exception'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:284:in `rescue in log'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:63:in `exec_insert'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:367:in `create'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:58:in `create'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in create'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__58360460__create__915097608__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `block in create_or_update'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__58360460__save__915097608__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:323:in `block in set_session'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb:50:in `silence'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/session_store.rb:320:in `set_session'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:327:in `commit_session'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:211:in `context'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__42731031__call__915097608__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  (gem) eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  (gem) thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  (gem) rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  (gem) railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what causes it and usually I'm good for another dump import and usually the problem vanish.

My session_store.rb looks like this:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: 'my_session_name', :domain => :all
```

The migration file to create the cookies session:

```
class AddSessionsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sessions do |t|
      t.string :session_id, :null => false
      t.text :data
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :sessions, :session_id
    add_index :sessions, :updated_at
  end
end
```

Because I can't explain why things don't work AND can't fix it unless I do another import, I'm wary of deleting old sessions in production.